# Using Mysqlii_query result object to check if the return value match the desired result

Tags: php, mysqli

So I want to search the database and return a result, take a look at this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT workforce from users WHERE email='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($result == "General"){
echo "General Category";
}else
echo "Manager Category"
```

I found out that the result returned is not a string but an object, thus I am unable to find a way to achieve the desired result.

For this example I am expecting a single result. Also I want to return the result to a android code via Volley Library which I have already done.
I am stuck with the php part since I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Forget to fetch data from result set. Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

Read for more info :   [mysqli_query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)    [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

```
    $sql = "SELECT workforce from users WHERE email='$username'";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($row['category'] == 'general') {
               echo 'general category';
            }else 
            {
               echo 'manager category';
            }

         }
     } else {
         echo "0 results";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
<?
$sql = "SELECT workforce from users WHERE email='$username'";
if($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)): //check query
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row['workforce'] == "General") { 
echo "General Category";
} else {
echo "Manager Category"
}
endif;
```